# Any sequence which has two subsequences converging to two different real numbers diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = A \Leftrightarrow $ each and every subsequences of {$a_n$} converges to A.
How can i prove that statements below
$$ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_{2n} = A\ \mbox{ and } \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_{2n-1} = A \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = A $$
$$ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_{2n} = A\ \mbox{ and } \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_{2n-1} = B ,\ A \ne B \Rightarrow {a_n}\ \mbox{ diverges } $$

Comment: If $A \neq B$, $\left| A -B \right| = \delta > 0$. Now the entire sequence should be $\delta / 2$ away from both $A$ and $B$ simultaneously for large $n$. Then use triangle inequality. You should be able to work out the details by yourself.